# Como obter apenas elementos específicos de uma página via axios.get()?

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, axios

Com o método axios.get da biblioteca axios.js eu consigo obter uma página HTML inteira, certo?
Exemplo:

```
  axios.get('http://www.umaurl.com')
                .then(resp => {
                    console.log(resp)

                })
```

Mas agora, se eu quiser buscar apenas alguns elementos específicos dessa página, como algumas divs, como eu poderia fazer isso numa requisição get via Axios? Teria que passar um seletor por exemplo, no objeto que é o segundo parâmetro do axios.get, certo? Mas como exatamente ficaria a sintaxe disso?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) para fazer isso.

```
 const cheerio = require('cheerio');
 const axios   = require('axio');

 axios.get('http://www.umaurl.com')
                .then(resp => {
                  $ = cheerio.load(resp.data);
                  var elemento = $('input[id="elemento"]') /// sintax do jquery
                  /// agora você faz o que quiser com o elemento
                })
```

Comment: Maravilha, vou testar primeiro

Comment: Ah, mas tem um detalhe: na verdade eu estou tentando dar GET, e não post. Eu quero dar GET em URLs externas, mas elas sempre recusam essas minhas requisições XMLHttpRequest do axios. Veja nesse tópico https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/452749/como-chamar-e-obter-via-get-uma-p%c3%a1gina-html-externa-usando-axios

Comment: Eu testei o seu código aqui e eu não obtive o mesmo erro