# Como chamar e obter via GET uma página HTML externa, usando Axios?

Tags: html, ajax, axios

Estou tentando obter uma página html externa qualquer via um axios.get(), passando a url da página em questão como parâmetro:

```
axios.get("http://www.google.com")
        .then(resp => {
            retorno = resp.body
         })
```

Só que o servidor dessas páginas externas nega o acesso e retorna o seguinte no browser da minha aplicação:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google.com/' (redirected from 'http://www.google.com/') from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

Não sei se isso é possível de ser feito assim. Se não, tem outra forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A razão é segurança. Os navegadores não permitem que scripts façam requisição de conteúdo de páginas com domínio diferente do qual ele está sendo rodado. (e.g: seu script está sendo rodado em www.suaurl.com.br e dessa url ele requisita conteúdo da página www.google.com), a não ser que o site destino (www.google.com) habilite CORS e permita que o site que roda o seu script (www.suaurl.com.br) requisite. (veja em: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS). No caso do amigo acima funcionou porque provavelmente ele está rodando o código no backend (usando node) .

Comment: Então se eu rodar isso no back-end com Node deve funcionar?

Answer (score 1):

Eu testei o seu código e não consegui reproduzir esse erro. Porém, se você quer a pagina html você tem que usar `resp.data` e não `resp.body`.

Se você não encontrar uma solução, eu sugiro que tente o [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Ex:

```
const request = require('request');
 request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
   retorno = body;
});
```

Comment: Poisé, que bizarro. Eu estou tentando obter a página principal do Google mesmo.

Comment: Mas vou tentar o require, um instante

Comment: O HTML vem na variável body da callbacak, mas não consigo usar o valor dela fora dessa função: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/452761/obter-html-de-url-externa-usando-m%c3%b3dulo-request-do-node