# Como utilizar valor de variável fora de sua callback? Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, request

Estou tentando obter o HTML de uma URL qualquer (do Google por exemplo), pra usá-la no meu front-end. Primeiro, eu tento no meu server.js Node com Express obter esse HTML através do módulo "request":

```
app.get('/geradorPreview', (req, res) =>{
    var retorno = null
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
       console.log(body) //IMPRIME CORRETAMENTE O HTML
        retorno = body;
     })
      console.log(retorno) // imprime null
     res.send({ret: retorno})
})
```

No primeiro console.log, o que é impresso no meu terminal é o HTML que eu requisitei. Então eu tento atribuir esse conteúdo do body pra variável retorno. Mas ao dar console.log nela a seguir, ela continua null, e eu não consigo usar o conteúdo da variável body.

Dicas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

joga o `res.send({ret: retorno})` para dentro da função de callback do request

o que esta acontecendo é que request é assíncrono quando   a engine do node está executando seu código ele lê o request faz uma chamada assincronia e passa para a próxima instrução, porem a próxima instrução ja é `console.log(retorno)` que esta retornando null pois a chamada assíncrona ainda não foi concluída, ou seja ainda não foi atribuído nenhum valor a variável null

se você analisar os parâmetros da função request há 2 argumentos `request(url, callback)`

o primeiro é a url ue no seu caso é `http://www.google.com`

o segundo é a função de call back que no seu caso é 
`function (error, response, body) {
       console.log(body) //IMPRIME CORRETAMENTE O HTML
        retorno = body;
})`

Quando a chamada assíncrona é concluída é executado a função de call back logo você tem que colocar o es.send(retorno)` dentro da função de callback para seu programa retorna somente quando a chamada assíncrona estiver sido concluída

Dê uma pesquisada em funções de callback , Promise, await/async